# TextBox does not extend its width and height when text is set codebehind

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, textbox

I have a textbox whose text is binded to a property.
When I enter on it manually, it just extends its width to show all of the text.

However, when I change the property from codebehind, textbox does not extend to its required width and height.

My textbox:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding TranslationText}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="2" materialDesign:HintAssist.IsFloating="True" materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="Text to translate" Name="TranslateBox" TextChanged="TranslateBox_OnTextChanged" HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" AcceptsReturn="True" ></TextBox>
```

How do I set it with codebehind:

```
this.TranslationText = "a very long text..";
OnPropertyChanged("TranslationText");
```

After I set it in codebehind, text gets updated, but textbox does not extend its width and height.

Comment: Well, if you are downvoting; tell me the reason so I can improve the question.

Comment: Is the width set to auto?

Comment: It isn't set to anything, so it should be auto.

Comment: so what happens when you set a long string?

Comment: It's width stays same and text is just partly visible and needs to be scrolled. I want it to increase its height automatically.

Comment: did you try to set it to auto and it was still not updating?

Answer (score 0):

call `UpdateLauout`.

```
<TextBox x:Name="tb" Text="{Binding TranslationText}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="2" materialDesign:HintAssist.IsFloating="True" materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="Text to translate" Name="TranslateBox" TextChanged="TranslateBox_OnTextChanged" HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" AcceptsReturn="True" >
```

c#

```
this.TranslationText = "a very long text..";
tb.UpdateLayout();
OnPropertyChanged("TranslationText");
```

Comment: did you try to set the width to auto?

Comment: Width worked now, but its height sitll not extending.

Comment: what do you mean by height the wrap?

Comment: Now its width increases as its required, but it is still one line even though text is multiline.

Comment: does it have newline characters

Comment: It does, since it is multiline